# Live streaming data from PC to PC in c++

Tags: c++, qt, sockets

I'm new in sending and receiving data from one PC to another. Currently i have an application in c++ generating data in Ubuntu where i need to stream those data from packet by packets to my mac. I have been told to use RapidJson and CRUL. But i found it difficult to understand. Im not sure which one will be the best solutions as match to my situation
1) An application in c++ running in Ubuntu continuous generating data at PC-a.
2) At PC-b i have an QT c++ running in Mac application where need to receive those data live from PC-a
3) At PC-b must know it must listening to only PC-a receiving data.

Is anyone can help to provide a sample simple example so that i follow?

Comment: If you have Qt on both sides look at their tcp examples. Also what type of data do yo stream?

Comment: QTcpServer is your friend. You can build a listener quite quickly. There is a tutorial here; http://www.bogotobogo.com/Qt/Qt5_QTcpServer_Client_Server.php

Comment: Thanks guys! i will try QTcpServer and install both side.